# Renderizar una vista que recibe valores del layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Buen dia!

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Estoy trabajando con Asp.net[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte roja es  la que conforma mi layout y la parte en azul es el lugar en donde quiero estar renderizando distintas graficas.

El problema es que no se de que manera puedo mandar los valores de los select que tengo en mi layout y mandarlos al backend para que me regrese la vista que necesito

Estoy trabajando con el MVC de Asp.net

Comment: Puedes tener algun boton que diga actualizar grafica y en el evento click haces un llamado al servidor, enviando los parametros de tus controles.

Comment: Vistas parciales :D Por otro lado, revisa este enlace: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 te ayudará a mejorar la forma de preguntar